# In PHP, how do we return a large array?

Tags: php

Say if this is the code:

```
function bar() {
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
        $result[] = $i * 10;
    }
    return $result;
}

$ha = bar();
print_r($ha);
```

Is it not efficient to return a large array like that since it is "return by value"? (say if it is not 1000 but 1000000).  So to improve it, would we change the first line to:

```
function &bar() {
```

that is, just by adding an `&` in front of the function name -- is this a correct and preferred way if a large array is returned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a lot of misunderstanding about how PHP handles variable storage.  Since PHP is "copy on write," there is no need to create a "reference" (actually a symbol table alias) in an effort to save space or time.  In fact, doing so can hurt you.  You should *only* create a reference in PHP if you want to use it as an alias to something.  I ran both of your snippets, and it looks like the second actually uses *more* memory (though not by much).

By the way, an array of 1000 integers is *tiny*.

Answer (score 5):

They consume **absolutely** the same amount of memory, because of [COW](http://www.research.ibm.com/trl/people/mich/pub/200901_popl2009phpsem.pdf)

1. http://ideone.com/bZgm7
2. http://ideone.com/e3Jfr

PS: to get "true" passing by reference you also need to add it in the assignment:

```
$ha =& bar();
```

Comment: Only function definitions can have reference signs, not function calls

Comment: @Jack: please read documentation (*carefully*) and undownvote me: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php (especially see the first Note: "Unlike parameter passing, here you have to use & in both places")

Comment: My apologies, I stand corrected .. pretty obscure stuff I must say :)

Comment: Blame the system for not being able to undo my downvote after 8mins :(

Answer (score 3):

If you throw in a `memory_get_peak_usage()` in the function and outside, you'll see that returning the array does not increase the memory.

PHP copies on write. In this case, there is nothing to copy even if you do write because the original variable is out of scope. So no, there is no reason to do this.

And in fact, in PHP, there's generally no reason to use references unless you need the *functionality* that they provide: altering the original variable.

Comment: So, after we take back the array, if we immediate change one array element or add one element to the array, it is considered a "write", but there will be no "copy on write"?

Comment: @Jeremy L: if you change the array outside the function - only one reference exists, thus no copies will be done. So it will be considered as a write, but without copies (because only one reference exists)

Comment: @Jeremy L: there will be no copy on write due to it being the only reference to that array. If you were returning an instance variable of an object, then there would be a copy after you modify the array. However, in that case, you would have to ask yourself: do I really want the caller to be able to alter the object's instance array? So again, I would repeat that as a rule of thumb you don't use references in PHP to gain performance.

Answer (score 1):

Official manual page says: Returning by reference is useful when you want to use a function to find to which variable a reference should be bound. Do not use return-by-reference to increase performance. The engine will automatically optimize this on its own. Only return references when you have a valid technical reason to do so

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php

So, in your case, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
function bar($result) {
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
        $result[] = $i * 10;
    }
}

bar(&$ha);
print_r($ha);
```